# Combine two categorical columns to create binary columns for each pairwise combination

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to take two columns of traits and generate pairwise combinations for a correlation analysis. I start with a data frame that looks like this:

```
            Sex Age Harvest_DPI
M_1_10w_M_L   1  10           0
M_2_10w_M_L   1  10           0
M_3_10w_M_L   1  10           0
M_1_10w_2_L   1  10           2
M_2_10w_2_L   1  10           2
M_3_10w_2_L   1  10           2
M_1_10w_4_L   1  10           4
M_2_10w_4_L   1  10           4
M_3_10w_4_L   1  10           4
M_1_10w_7_L   1  10           7
M_2_10w_7_L   1  10           7
M_3_10w_7_L   1  10           7
M_1_20w_M_L   1  20           0
M_2_20w_M_L   1  20           0
M_3_20w_M_L   1  20           0
M_1_20w_2_L   1  20           2
M_2_20w_2_L   1  20           2
M_3_20w_2_L   1  20           2
M_1_20w_4_L   1  20           4
M_2_20w_4_L   1  20           4
M_3_20w_4_L   1  20           4
M_2_20w_7_L   1  20           7
M_3_20w_7_L   1  20           7
```

And, what I'd like is to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
            Sex 10_0  10_2  10_4 10_7 20_0 20_2 20_4 20_7
M_1_10w_M_L   1    1     0     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_M_L   1    1     0     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_M_L   1    1     0     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_2_L   1    0     1     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_2_L   1    0     1     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_2_L   1    0     1     0    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_4_L   1    0     0     1    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_4_L   1    0     0     1    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_4_L   1    0     0     1    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_7_L   1    0     0     0    1    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_7_L   1    0     0     0    1    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_7_L   1    0     0     0    1    0    0    0    0
M_1_20w_M_L   1    0     0     0    0    1    0    0    0
M_2_20w_M_L   1    0     0     0    0    1    0    0    0
M_3_20w_M_L   1    0     0     0    0    1    0    0    0
M_1_20w_2_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    1    0    0
M_2_20w_2_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    1    0    0
M_3_20w_2_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    1    0    0
M_1_20w_4_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    0    1    0
M_2_20w_4_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    0    1    0
M_3_20w_4_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    0    1    0
M_2_20w_7_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    0    0    1
M_3_20w_7_L   1    0     0     0    0    0    0    0    1
```

with the pattern continuing for a 3rd age group.

I've tried using the binarizeCategoricalColumns function from the WGCNA package but that just does the combinations within each trait instead of across traits. Also, I was unable to find a question that was similar to mine here on the site. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` - create the rownames as column (as tidyverse wouldn't allow row names), `unite` the columns 'Age', 'Harvest_DPI' to a single column, use `pivot_wider` to reshape to wide and specify the `values_fn` as `length`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
   unite(AgeHarvest, Age, Harvest_DPI) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = AgeHarvest, values_from = AgeHarvest, 
    values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('rn')
```

-output

```
          Sex 10_0 10_2 10_4 10_7 20_0 20_2 20_4 20_7
M_1_10w_M_L   1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_M_L   1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_M_L   1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_2_L   1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_2_L   1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_2_L   1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_4_L   1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_4_L   1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_4_L   1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
M_1_10w_7_L   1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
M_2_10w_7_L   1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
M_3_10w_7_L   1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
M_1_20w_M_L   1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
M_2_20w_M_L   1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
M_3_20w_M_L   1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
M_1_20w_2_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
M_2_20w_2_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
M_3_20w_2_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
M_1_20w_4_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
M_2_20w_4_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
M_3_20w_4_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
M_2_20w_7_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
M_3_20w_7_L   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Age = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), Harvest_DPI = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("M_1_10w_M_L", 
"M_2_10w_M_L", "M_3_10w_M_L", "M_1_10w_2_L", "M_2_10w_2_L", "M_3_10w_2_L", 
"M_1_10w_4_L", "M_2_10w_4_L", "M_3_10w_4_L", "M_1_10w_7_L", "M_2_10w_7_L", 
"M_3_10w_7_L", "M_1_20w_M_L", "M_2_20w_M_L", "M_3_20w_M_L", "M_1_20w_2_L", 
"M_2_20w_2_L", "M_3_20w_2_L", "M_1_20w_4_L", "M_2_20w_4_L", "M_3_20w_4_L", 
"M_2_20w_7_L", "M_3_20w_7_L"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you could try

```r
uniq_df <- expand.grid(unique(df$Harvest_DPI), unique(df$Age))

cbind(df[1:2], setNames(as.data.frame(apply(uniq_df, 1, function(x) {
  as.numeric(df$Age == x[2] & df$Harvest_DPI == x[1])
  })), apply(uniq_df, 1, function(x) paste(x[2], x[1],  sep = "_"))))
#>             Sex Age 10_0 10_2 10_4 10_7 20_0 20_2 20_4 20_7
#> M_1_10w_M_L   1  10    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_2_10w_M_L   1  10    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_3_10w_M_L   1  10    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_1_10w_2_L   1  10    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_2_10w_2_L   1  10    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_3_10w_2_L   1  10    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_1_10w_4_L   1  10    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_2_10w_4_L   1  10    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_3_10w_4_L   1  10    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> M_1_10w_7_L   1  10    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#> M_2_10w_7_L   1  10    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#> M_3_10w_7_L   1  10    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#> M_1_20w_M_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> M_2_20w_M_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> M_3_20w_M_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> M_1_20w_2_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> M_2_20w_2_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> M_3_20w_2_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> M_1_20w_4_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> M_2_20w_4_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> M_3_20w_4_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> M_2_20w_7_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> M_3_20w_7_L   1  20    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data frame name is `data1` then you can do this

```
data1 = cbind(
    data1,
    as.data.frame.matrix(
        table(1:nrow(data1), paste(data1$Age, data1$Harvest_DPI, sep="_"))
    )
)
```

edit::
If you want to have all the combinations (even the ones that are not present in the dataset), you can consider the below

```
expand1 = expand.grid(Age=unique(data1$Age), Harvest_DPI=unique(data1$Harvest_DPI))
data1$Class = factor(paste(data1$Age, data1$Harvest_DPI, sep="_"), levels=paste(expand1$Age, expand1$Harvest_DPI, sep="_"))
data1 = cbind(
    data1,
    as.data.frame.matrix(
        table(1:nrow(data1), paste(data1$Age, data1$Harvest_DPI, sep="_"))
    )
)
```